# How can i attach array objects to a curve while animating?

Tags: animation, modifiers

i made an object and then applied the array modifier, then i attached it to a curve with the curve modifier, and it looks good but if i move the curve ( i need to animate it ) the spheres moves weird, apart from the curve...is there any way to fix this? :(

Thanks in regard.

[image]

Comment: You need to move both, the origins need to stay in the same orientation in relation to each other

Comment: Is there an option to only move the curve and make the spheres copy the same parametters in order to just move one object? it will be difficult if not, or maybe i'll be limited.

Comment: Copy location constraint maybe?

Comment: @beavoru Add an empty and parent it to both objects, with the keep offer option

Comment: You mean keep offset... :)

Comment: @beavoru Did anything work?

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't able to answer, i'll tell you later, i'll try, thanks :)

Comment: It worked, but if i move the curve, it doesnt work for animation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- parent the spheres to the curve so when you move the curve the sphere will follow
- animate the curve using shape key

[image]